# Postgres function to merge two json objects with overlapping keys into one object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've got the following json object:

```
{
    "a" : {
        "0" : 2,
        "1" : 4,
        "3" : 6,
    }
    "b" : {
        "2" : 8,
        "1" : 10, /*note this key exists in "a" too*/
        "4" : 12,
    }
}
```

I'd like to generate the following object and then be able to extract an element from it like so:

```
{
        "0" : 2,
        "1" : 10,
        "2" : 8,
        "3" : 6,
        "4" : 12,
}
```

Extraction: `object->>'1'` should return `'10'`

Basically I have two arrays with potentially overlapping keys and I want to merge the two, giving one array precedence.

How can I accomplish this? Ideally I'd call a function like `arrayMerge(a, b)` and it gave `'a'` higher precedence than `'b'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer concerns **Postgres 9.4 and 9.3.**

Example data:

```
create table test_js(val jsonb);
insert into test_js values ('{"a":{"0":2,"1":4,"3":6},"b":{"1":10,"2":8,"4":12}}');
```

First, retrieve all pairs with arbitrary chosen priorities:

```
select 0 priority, jsonb_each(val->'b') elem
from test_js
union all
select 1 priority, jsonb_each(val->'a') elem
from test_js
order by 1

 priority |  elem  
----------+--------
        0 | (1,10)
        0 | (2,8)
        0 | (4,12)
        1 | (0,2)
        1 | (1,4)
        1 | (3,6)
(6 rows)
```

Next, from the resultset select elements with unique keys:

```
select distinct on ((elem).key) elem
from (
    select 0 priority, jsonb_each(val->'b') elem
    from test_js
    union all
    select 1 priority, jsonb_each(val->'a') elem
    from test_js
    ) sub

  elem  
--------
 (0,2)
 (1,10)
 (2,8)
 (3,6)
 (4,12)
(5 rows)
```

Finally, aggregate the result into a json object:

```
select json_object_agg((elem).key, (elem).value) result
from (
    select distinct on ((elem).key) elem
    from (
        select 0, jsonb_each(val->'b') elem
        from test_js
        union all
        select 1, jsonb_each(val->'a') elem
        from test_js
        ) sub
    ) sub

                      result                       
---------------------------------------------------
 { "0" : 2, "1" : 10, "2" : 8, "3" : 6, "4" : 12 }
(1 row)
```

In **Postgres 9.3** you can simulate `json_object_agg` using `string_agg`:

```
select format('{ %s }', 
    string_agg(format('"%s" : %s', (elem).key, (elem).value), ', '))::json result
from (
    select distinct on ((elem).key) elem
    from (
        select 0, json_each(val->'b') elem
        from test_js
        union all
        select 1, json_each(val->'a') elem
        from test_js
        ) sub
    ) sub

                      result                       
---------------------------------------------------
 { "0" : 2, "1" : 10, "2" : 8, "3" : 6, "4" : 12 }
(1 row)
```

Btw, your json value is invalid, should be

```
{
    "a": {
        "0": 2,
        "1": 4,
        "3": 6
    },
    "b": {
        "1": 10,
        "2": 8,
        "4": 12
    }
}
```

Please, use [JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to validate json values.

Comment: Is this more efficient than simply `CASE WHEN coalesce(a->>'1', '-1') = '-1' THEN coalesce(b->>'1', '-1') ELSE coalesce(a->>'1', '-1') END`?

Comment: Probably there is no huge difference in performance, but it's hard to imagine a query with several dozen such comparisons. The solution in the answer is simply more general.

Comment: Purely for the sake of discussion, do you know if json objects are hashed in Postgres? If so, my `CASE` statement might be faster because it uses the existing hash table rather than building a new hash table for your new object? Yours probably is much faster as the number of times you reference the object increases towards infinity (mine is O(3n) and yours is O(n) where n is the number of times you query the object I believe?)

Comment: Yes, it seems likely. For a small `n` simple comparison may be a bit faster. With increasing `n` the general query should be getting better.

Comment: Shoot. I actually forgot to mention I'm on postgres 9.3. Do you have any ideas for a way to do it without `json_object_agg`? I'll leave it as the answer.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough, but is `order by 1` necessary? Dropping leading numbers for sort and using `union all` should ensure first record set to be always above the second one? Ie. https://gist.github.com/mpapec/4dc57d58258c07d6803a846915214e0b

Comment: `union all` does not guarantee the sort order, but otherwise you're perfectly right. `order by 1` is redundant and added only to get nice output in the first example. Also, in this case `union all` is better than `union`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In **Postgres 9.5+** you can simply use the built-in concatenation operator `||` to merge JSON objects.

```
create table test_js(val jsonb);
insert into test_js values ('{"a":{"0":2,"1":4,"3":6},"b":{"1":10,"2":8,"4":12}}');

select (val->'a') || (val->'b') from test_js;
                  ?column?
--------------------------------------------
 {"0": 2, "1": 10, "2": 8, "3": 6, "4": 12}
(1 row)
```

Comment: what's up with `?column?`?

Comment: The output column is the result of a function, and thus has no name.  You could name it by adding `AS new_column` to the select statement.